# Package.json dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

we are developing an business framework based on Angular.
At the moment all the final products, that are using our framework must also add dependencies for Angular and ~20 other libraries that we demand into the package.json of the product. It is always a big hustle to ensure the everybody upgrades to the right version of the other libs, when our libraries demands newer versions.

Is there a way to just add one dependency to our business framework and some mechanism automatically adds als other dependencies.

On the backend side we are using Maven and everything is perfect. Just a more or less empty pom file with one dependency to our framework lib. In the pom file of the framework lib all other dependenies are defined. I would expect to have somethink similar also in the npm world.

Regards,
Johannes

Comment: Peer dependencies is what you need.

It ensure the consumers of the package has some minimal requirements.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that I need npm 7 or higher, to ensure that the peerDependencies are installed. So I can move all dependencies into my business lib and remove them from my projects. Is there a way to also update the devDependencies? E.g. the angular tooling.